# Deploying ASP.NET Web API App to IIS 7 On Different Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I have been literally stuck for hours trying to deploy a Web API app to IIS. I can not believe there are no useful tutorials online anywhere that I can find. Here is my situation.

- I have a VERY basic Web API app. It is using .NET Framework 4.0. It doesn't do anything I just want to see the home page at this point.
- I am developing it in Visual Studio 2012 on my local machine. I can hit my localhost and see the home page, even post some data through Fiddler works great.
- I publish the solution using Build->Publish to my local file system.
- I then copy and paste everything in that directory to my web server (actually using a repository but for simplicity sake)
- I created a brand new application pool in IIS. .NET 4.0 Integrated.
- I placed the folder that contains my published code inside of the directory of my main website. The folder name is WebAPI.
- I created a new website in IIS, attached to that new app pool I created.
- I start the website, browse it on localhost and everything works perfectly.
- I try to go to the website externally "website.com/WebAPI/api" and get a

  403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, I've never deployed an MVC app to IIS on another server. I'm able to deploy it just fine on my local machine through IIS too. What am I missing? Thanks!

Edit: Yes, my server has other .NET 4.0 apps running just fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you run it locally you can "see the home page" of a web api project. Post the api code and the url that you see that on pls.

Comment: Have you considered using Web Deploy instead of File System publishing? What is your Target Location when you publish?

Comment: Hey, am stuck with same thing. Did you find out what was wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem did you find anything, Thanks!

Comment: @KJ3...any solution? stuck with same problem. how to deploy and access url like this
http://website.com/WebAPI/api

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost/api
http://website.com/WebAPI/api
```

Is this correct?

If so, looks like it could be a path problem.